# Сделать поиск пользователей из базы данных через форму в админке Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Нужно сделать поиск по таблице users через форму поиска внутри моей админки.

В users.php есть вывод всех пользователей из базы данных. Не понимаю как сделать поиск по этому полученному выводу, чтобы осталось только то значение, которое я указал в форме поиска. Значение по которому буду искать - email.

Searchuserme.php - модель

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class  extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{users}}';
    }


}
```

SearchusermeController.php - контроллер

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use app\models\Blog;
use app\models\Categories;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\Searchuserme;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;


class SearchusermeController extends Controller
{




    public function actionSearch($params) 
    {
        $q = trim(Yii::$app->request->get('q'));
        if(!$q) return $this->render('search');
        $query = Searchuserme::find()->where(['email', $q]);
        /*$pages = new Pagination([
        'totalCount' => $query->count(),
        'pageSize' => 1,
        'forcePageParam' => false,
        'pageSizeParam' => false
        ]);*/
        $users = $query->orderBy(' DESC')
                ->offset($pages->offset)
                ->limit($pages->limit)
                ->all();
            return $this->render('search', compact('email','q'));
    }

}
```

users.php - view

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use dosamigos\fileupload\FileUploadUI;
use app\models\User;
use app\models\Searchuserme;

$this->title = 'Пользователи';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

?>

<div id="content-container">

    <div id="page-title">
        <h1 class="page-header text-overflow"><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    </div>


    <div id="page-content">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="col-lg-12">

<form action="<?=\yii\helpers\Url::to(['admin/users'])?>" method="get" class="search-form" role="search">
  <input id="search-field" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Искать ..." class="hint" autocomplete="off" />
  <button id="search-submit" type="submit">Найти</button>

</form>
</div>

    <div id="page-content">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Balance</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Username</th>
                                <th>Full Name</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <? foreach ($model as $key => $value): ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href="<?= Url::to(['admin/user-edit', 'id' => $value->id]); ?>"><?= Yii::t('site', 'Edit'); ?></a></td>
                                    <td><?= $value->balance; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $value->email; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $value->username; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $value->fullName; ?></td>
                                    <td><?= $value->id; ?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <? endforeach; ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал просто воспользоваться `gii` генератором и сгенерировать контроллер, модель и представления,  в том числе и поиск

Comment: @СергейМишин согласен, наверно самый простой путь, но не я писал проект, бросил меня мой программист, сам не понимаю yii2, собственно поэтому спрашиваю как это слепить из того, что описал выше. Вроде как совсем чуть чуть не хватает) В любом случае спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем разобрался сам.

Ошибка была в модели Searchuserme.php

правильная модель:

```
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Searchuserme extends ActiveRecord
{

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{users}}';
    }


}
```

Далее в users.php - view по совету [Haku Kimura](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/342892/haku-kimura)

добавил

```
$q = trim(Yii::$app->request->get('q'));
        $searching = Searchuserme::find()->where(['email'=>$q])->one();

<td><a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" href="<?= Url::to(['admin/user-edit', 'id' => $searching->userId]); ?>"><?= Yii::t('site', 'Edit'); ?></a></td>
        <td><?= $searching->balance; ?></td>
        <td><?= $searching->email; ?></td>
        <td><?= $searching->username; ?></td>
        <td><?= $searching->fullName; ?></td>
        <td><?= $searching->userId; ?></td>
```

И все заработало.

Comment: Рекомендация: никаких запросов на получение или изменение данных в представлениях быть не должно, все взаимодействия с БД должны находиться в контроллерах или моделях (в вашем случае `actionSearch`).

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в этой строчке:

```php
$query = Searchuserme::find()->where(['email', $q]);
```

В методе `where()` условие нужно указывать в одном из следующих форматов:

- строковый формат: `'status=1'`,
- формат массива: `['status' => 1, 'type' => 2]`,
- формат операторов: `['like', 'name', 'test']`.

Соответственно, чтобы условие работало корректно вам нужно изменить аргумент на:
`['email' => $q]`.

[Подробная информация в документации Yii Framework](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-queryinterface#where()-detail)